# Xamarin Forms can't find my localized string

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to get a localized string:

```
Debug.WriteLine(AppResources.Duplicate);
```

But it gives me a TargetInvocationException. I don't get why, because the autocompletion indicates there are no problems. What could I be doing wrong?

Edit: now even the autocomplete is not able to find AppResources, I get errors even though it was working before.

Answer (score 0):

I've put my AppResources into a new folder called resources, I guess this is not allowed as it's a reserved name for a folder: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_resources/

I created a new RESX file, copy-pasted the contents to this new file which is not in a folder called resources and it's working again.